# mssql_bind empty string converting to NULL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, php-mssql

I am currently using SQL Server 2000 Stored Procedures with PHP. Following the PHP doc, I use **[mssql_bind](https://www.php.net/mssql_bind)** to assign value of parameters and then execute the Stored Procedure.

The problem is that I got [this bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40394) which prevents me to bind empty strings to parameters (they are converted to NULL when the Stored Proc gets called)

I dont't want to have to convert every parameter inside the Stored Procedures to check if its NULL then convert back to an empty string. I want to be able to use empty strings as well as NULL which both have their own meaning.

Does anyone know a workaround for this in PHP ? PHP bugs website isn't very clear if that bug is fixed or when it will be fixed, I use PHP 5.2.11 (the lastest version from the 5.2 branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to do what you suggested, options left to you are

1. Download a cvs snapshot of php and install it if viable, see if it is fixed.  If not viable or fixed via cvs then...
2. Use system() or exec() calls to use the stored procedures.  If too much a hassle then...
3. Don't use stored procedures, do your functionality in php or other scripting code.
4. Alter the stored procedure to accept another value for '' strings and convert THAT to a '' string.
5. Do what you didn't want to do.  Harsh :P But I do not see another way.

Answer (score 0):

The [bug #44325](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44325) proposed a patch to solve the problem, but it was not a correct solution, as it seems the problem is in ntwdblib.dll, and not in the code of the php_mssql extension.

See the comment from alexr at oplot dot com :

> I'm sorry. This bug is not fixed. This
>   is a bug of the ntwdblib.dll. And
>   after latest updates the bug is
>   return.
>
> When I bind a empty string, the stored
>   procedure received a chr(0) char
>   instead a empty string.
>
> Please roll back last fixes. This bug
>   is irrecoverable.

Considering this, I'm not sure there's much that could be done on the PHP side :-(

Last time I worked with PHP+MSSQL on Windows, I had quite a lot of problems, like some quite similar to this one, actually ;-(

Maybe a possible solution, for you, might be to switch to the newer [SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/PHP-Driver.aspx) driver ? Note that is only works on Windows, though...

Comment: Yeah, that is the problem, we are running PHP on Linux, so we can't use the new driver.

Also, isn't ntwdblib.dll a Windows component ? So it should not affect the Linux version of PHP, or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't have a MSSQL server available to test but have you tried using PDO instead of mssql directly?

```
PDOStatement->bindValue( mixed $parameter  , mixed $value  [, int $data_type  ] )
```

[bindValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Yes, I realize that PDO is only a wrapper but who knows, could work! :)

Comment: Yes we know that there is PDO, but it does not support multiple resultset a Stored Proc could return.

Comment: It was a longshot, too bad! :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that will work.

I am using ADODB (but that doesnt matter) and I have hacked the mssql driver (adodb-mssql.inc.php in the adodb5 drivers folder).

here is the code

```
if($var === ''){
        //stupid hack to prevent mssql driver from converting empty strings to null. now they arent empty strings but they will get trimmed down to legth 0 ;-)
        $var = ' ';
        $type = SQLVARCHAR;
        $isNull = false;
        $maxLen = 0;
    }
```

simply check if you are trying to bind an empty string and if you are change it to be non empty. it doesn't matter what value you use I just  use a space.

make the type a sqlvarchar isnull should be false and now the trick is to make maxlen 0 so that the mssql driver will trim your string to an empty string.

those variables should get passsed to the mssql_bind function if that wasn't obvious.